# two-line frame title error in beamer

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I getting an error when I try to add a two-line frame title (first frame in MWE). Can someone please point out error here

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\centerline{\textbf{\color{blue}{New Message \\ Hello World }}}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{New Message\\Hello World}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centerline` is one line, hence you need to add all closing `}`'s before `\\` (i.e. double backlash, but SE transformed it in a strange way).

Comment: I tried \frametitle{\centerline{\textbf{\color{blue}{New Message }}}\\\centerline{\textbf{\color{blue}{Hello World }}}} but now the two are not aligned. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case you need

- `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]` to center the frame title
- `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue}` for blue color
- `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=bfseries}` to change frame title font

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usetheme{default}    
\usecolortheme{default}    
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    
\let\familydefault\rmdefault
\begin{document}
{  
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]  
 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue} 
 \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=bfseries}   
 \begin{frame}   
 \frametitle{New Message \\ Hello World}   
 \end{frame}
}
\begin{frame}   
\frametitle{New Message\\Hello World}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

We changed color of `fg` for the `frametitle` with `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue}` inside group containing only the fist frame.

[image]